# What is a correct way to report desired size for UIView subclass?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am subclassing UIView and cannot find a right way to request/report its desired size. I expected `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` to do the trick, but it is never called. Layout is simple - I pin top and leading of my view and limit trailing and bottom to be less than or equal to top-level view. Among all sizing functions, only `intrinsicContentSize` is called, but that one is not very helpful.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class StatsView: UIView
{
  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
  {
    let context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
  }

  override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize
  {
    print("Called sizeThatFits with \(size)")
    if(size.width>350)
    {
      return CGSize(width: 350,height: 50)
    }
    else
    {
      return CGSize(width: 50,height: 100)
    }
  }

  override func systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(size: CGSize) -> CGSize
  {
    print("Called systemLayoutSizeFittingSize with \(size)")
    return super.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(size)
  }

  override func systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(size: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize
  {
    print("Called systemLayoutSizeFittingSize with \(size)")
    if(size.width>350)
    {
      return CGSize(width: 350,height: 50)
    }
    else
    {
      return CGSize(width: 50,height: 100)
    }
  }

  override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize
  {
    super.intrinsicContentSize()
    print("Called intrinsicContentSize")
    return CGSize(width: 10,height: 50)
  }
}
```

What is a right way to do it?

**Update** I want my view to have some info, not just a blue rectangle. There is some "optimal" width, but if the view cannot have that much from its parent, it can compensate by rearranging information to use more height. So, reporting constant values from `intrinsicContentSize` does not fit my needs.

Comment: Why you said that `intrinsicContentSize` isn't helpful? This is the exact place where you custom view can raport to the layout system its desired size.

Comment: @psci Please, look at the code. I want my custom view to have some info, not just a blue rectangle. There is some "optimal" width, but if the view cannot have that much from it's parent, it can compensate by rearranging information to use more height. `intrinsicContentSize` does not have method's parameters saying how much space view can take. I updated my question to mention it.

Comment: This is an interesting question. It may help to have a more descriptive title. As has been answered, `intrinsicContentSize` is the correct way to report the desired size of a `UIView`, but your question is how can you specify **multiple** valid sizes. Unfortunately I don't think this is possible with auto layout out of the box.

Comment: @Dmitry I have a very similar use case, and the answers here are not really helping. Have you figured it out at some point?

Comment: @manmal Not the way I wanted to. I've left `sizeThatFits` function in a view, which has to be called by ViewController ( Something like this:

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  {
    updateHeight()
  }

  fileprivate func updateHeight()
  {
    stats.layoutIfNeeded()
    let wantedSize=stats.sizeThatFits(stats.bounds.size)
    if wantedSize.height != statsHeightConstraint.constant
    {
      statsHeightConstraint.constant=wantedSize.height
      view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
  }

Comment: Thank you. In the meantime I've somewhat hacked it. In my case, it's multiple nested views within a UITableViewController, and not even full width. I've taken to injecting the target width in the constructor in the leaf view, so the leaf view knows what width it should layout to. Not great, but gets the job done.

Comment: Cannot say I like any of these solutions (

Answer (score 7):

You use `intrinsicContentSize` to report the desired size of your view based off of it's contents. This value can change as the contents change, but you need to call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` when it does.

This `intrinsicContentSize` works along with `contentHuggingPriority`, `contentCompressionResistancePriority`, and the other layout constraints in the superview to determine the actual layout size.

In your case it sounds like you want to report an ideal size based off of the contents of your view, change the size and invalidate it if the content changes, and use layout constraints with sibling views and the parent view to compress (or resist) as needed.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer seems too general. Let me give an example - UILabel can arrange it's height to be 1 line in landscape mode and 2 lines in portrait or if it gets only half of the width. I want to achieve a similar effect.
There is no content changes here and being the only subview in the parent view, hugging and resistance do not really matter.
I know how to do it with the help of constraints on ViewControllers level, but UILabel does fine without it.

Comment: If you know how to do it with the help of constraints, then I suggest you do it that way. After all, that is how UILabel does it as well. How else do you think it "get's only half the width"?

Comment: The question is how does UILabel request more height in such case? It successfully reports what size it wants to be and if the enclosing width is not enough, it requests more height unless some constraints prevent it. Apparently there should be a way to do the same in custom view.

Comment: UILabel does not request more height, it is given it's width and height by it's constraints. It responds to this by rendering the text differently (according to `lines`, auto shrink, etc.) to use the space that has been given to it most efficiently. Likewise, you should be able to use constraints to achieve the sizing that you desire. There are several points at which you can hook into the layout process to adjust constraints if necessary. You also have the option of using size classes to define different sets of constraints. Without a more specific question, that's as much as I can help.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that in auto-layout environment `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` will not call even it change layout. It's a method to calculate the size of a view after view did finished layout.

The *intrinsic* content size is concerned only with data that is in the view itself, not in other views. Remember that you can also set constant width or height constraints on any view, and you don't need to override instrinsicContentSize if these dimensions won't be changing with changing view content

View will update it's content size if there is any update of it's constraint which is happened using `- (void)updateConstraints` method that means you could override this method to observe the changes of it's constraints. Since you wants to rearrange views in certain width condition so best practice is to put on this `- (void)layoutSubviews` method which will called on changes of view's frame.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews { 
    [super layoutSubviews];
    // do your view arrangement based on width
    // apple custom constraint here
}
```

Comment: I do not actually have subviews, only some custom drawing, but it may be a good idea. I will give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: I actually added some code to your answer, but it was deleted later :-( The problem is that `layoutSubviews` gets called if the view does not fit the limits, but not called otherwise. So, when I switch to having more width, I cannot resize to use it :-( But I like this answer more than the one above.

Comment: When you resize view? Would you please update your question with diagram/picture/screenshot which will help us to understand your problem clearly. Please note that layoutSubviews also get fire if you use         these method     

'- (void)setNeedsLayout; - (void)layoutIfNeeded;'  

Allows you to perform layout before the drawing cycle happens. -layoutIfNeeded forces layout early

Comment: I wanted to avoid unnecessary details. Basically it is a stats view with many details and a lot of complex drawing. But it does look better if it has enough width to fit everything it wants into 1 line. If not, it can do with less width and more height. It will also be embedded into scroll view, but, again, I wanted to solve it with the most simple situation. So, I simplified drawing function and left scroll view out of my question.